# Entity Framework apply filter with entities that have lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code using Entity Framework

```
 var test = _dbContext.Category
                      .Include(t => t.Items)
                      .Where(t => t.items.show == true)
                      .ToList();
```

A category has a list of items. However, I can not apply the filter `show == true`.

Why is it happening? How do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Besides, your `toList()` function name seems incorrect and it should be `ToList()`

Comment: check if items.show is string in db.

Comment: The problem is that I can not apply the filter Where(t=>t.items.show==true). Instead of being able to go to t.items.Show, I receive options related to lists. Please take into account taht items is a List<Items>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any` for this kind of request and you may avoid Include if you won't use items apart from filtering.

```
var test = _dbContext.Category
                      .Where(t => t.items.Any(item=> item.show == true))
                      .ToList();
```

P.S: I strongly recommend to use C# naming convention. `Items` and `Show` are more accurate if they are properties.

Comment: It won't include the items though

Comment: @SamArustamyan, OP's question contains Include not your answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell from the OP's question what the expected result is. Assuming he needs what you described in your answer your code will do.

Answer (score 3):

The items in `t=>t.items.show==true` is a collection not the individual item, so there is no `show` property.

If you need to load only the items with show==true you can load them separately:

```
var categories = _dbContext.Category.ToList();
var items = _dbContext.Category.SelectMany(x => x.Items).Where(x => x.show == true).ToList();
```

EF will attach the items to appropriate categories automatically.